# In need of a unique remote desktop/VNC solution

Tags: browser, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-control

I was wondering if there was a solution already created that would be all web browser based without having the need to connect to anything else other than the web server port if you were the client.

Ex: The server that has the VNC server on it, also has a built in web server which is a part of the VNC program. Is there a solution where the VNC server on that machine can stream its content to the web server using flash or something so that clients can just goto the web server and control the machine from there (using the flash interface and only communicating via http, no other sockets) without having to connect to the VNC server itself?

The thing is, I need this to all work as if you were just viewing a normal web page on the internet. There are network restrictions on the clients end that do not allow any tunnelling, anything other than HTTP traffic on HTTP ports, SSL VPN's, etc.

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: Windows XP on both ends
EDIT: However, I can make the machine that is running the VNC server a Linux one if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too well versed in web servers and everything, but [LogMeIn Free](https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/free/) is web-based on the client end (not the server)...

sorry if this doesn't work...just a suggestion...

Comment: I know people who use this program. I haven't tried it but I believe that it is more than just webpage based. It is also very popular so I wouldn't doubt that it is blocked at the location where I wish to remote my machine from. I will give it a try tomorrow though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: one thing I have found with work blocks and such, is that the filters often block http:// versus http **s** :// ...sometimes it helps to type up the site address with the extra 's' in http, versus click it in Google or Bing...

Comment: They are using some McAffee web filter that is the strictest I have come across yet. I just started this job yesterday, I tried all of my old tricks to get past it, but they all failed. I was shocked when Hamachi (SSL VPN) wouldn't even connect to its servers. I do however have access to my home router from work so I can play with port forwarding while I am there.

Comment: I've used it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309094/which-flash-ajax-based-vnc-viewer-do-you-recommend), which asks the same question.   A couple of the answers look promising, but I've never used any of them myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try all of these solutions tomorrow. My poor windows box is going to be loaded with remote software.

Comment: Link is dead, recommending deletion

Answer (score 1):

You state,

> The thing is, I need this to all work as if you were just viewing a normal web page on the internet. There are network restrictions on the clients end that do not allow any tunnelling, anything other than HTTP traffic on HTTP ports, SSL VPN's, etc.

But how can you tell if you are tunneling or not if it is over port 80? Set up your home router to accept ssh on port 80, then ssh out of the local machine into the router. Set up a tunnel, launch the VNC server on the remote machine, then point your local browser to the tunnel on 127.0.0.1.

Alternatively, can you ssh into work from home? If so, set up a reverse SSH tunnel from home, then connect to it on localhost when you are at work.

Comment: I have tried this. It doesn't work. I've been meaning to install Wireshark on the machine there to see what's going on.

EDIT: I have tried this on ports: 80, 443, 8080.

Comment: If you give more description of why it doesn't work it might help to debug why... Router not accepting ssh on 80? Need to do extra local tunneling to mask the outbound portion? etc. ssh has good verbose info when the flags are set.

Comment: Okay. I have sought up a SSH server in my home network here. I have tried forwarding port 80 to the SSH server within my network. I tried to PuTTY the SSH server from work on 80, no go. It just times out/no response.

Comment: http://www.dscoduc.com/2009/06/hiding-ssh-traffic-in-https-traffic/

Comment: Perhaps a 3rd party proxy? Also, you state you tried forwarding 80 from router to something in your home network, but did it succeed? And I'm not understanding your terminology: "I tried to PuTTY the SSH server from work on 80". Isn't the ssh server at home, and the ssh client at work?

Comment: I will try this all again tomorrow at work, I might have messed up when trying the SSH method. 

I have a SSH server at home on my network. I forwarded port 80 on my router at home to port 22 on the SSH server.

While at work, I tried to use PuTTY (SSH Client) to connect to port 80 at my home's IP Address. It would then proceed to timeout/fail. EDIT: I didn't have logging enabled on the SSH server so I cannot see whether or not if it connected at all.

Comment: Break it down in pieces. SSH into your home network from somewhere outside that isn't work, before you tackle work...

Answer (score 0):

[Yuuguu](http://www.yuuguu.com) will work with any flash-9 enabled browser.  The host machine needs to have the desktop client (Windows, Mac or Linux) installed.  You connect to a normal web page and enter the given PIN, the host can then share their screen and allow remote control.

Answer (score 0):

**EduVNC** worked perfect for my problem.

I tried the SSH tunnelling but that did not work because of the timeout policy set on the network.